# Among the subspaces $Y$ , $Z$, and $Y + Z$, which is/are closed in $X$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X = c_0$ be the space of complex sequences that converge to zero, equipped with the supremum norm. Consider the linear subspaces of $X$:

> $Y := \{ \{a_j\}: a_{2j-1} = 0$ for each $j = 1,2,3,...\}$;

> $Z := \{ \{b_j\}: b_{2j} = j_2b_{2j-1} = 0$ for each $j = 1,2,3,...\}$.

Among the subspaces $Y$ , $Z$, and $Y + Z$, which is/are closed in $X$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Are you sure these descriptions of $Y$ and $Z$ are correct? As currently described, $Z$ only contains the constant sequence $0$.

Comment: For $Y$ you could consider the mapping $$(a_1,a_2,a_3...)\mapsto (a_1,a_3,a_5,...)$$

Comment: The edit made $Z$ even worse. What is $j_2$ (before it was $j^2$)?